# Unable to enter a value in field using Xpath

Tags: selenium

I am unable to enter a value in field which is having type as "text" after running the automated script. Please find details below

Field Name: "Spot/Content Name
Xpath value for the above field :

```
.//*[@id='154']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input
```

Automated Script for the above Xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='154']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='154']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("Rose");
```

Error Message :

```
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='154']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input"}
```

I tried even the html which was shown on the xpath but it was not working.

Comment: Are you sure the element exists in your HTML code? What happens if you open the page in Chrome and type `$x(".//*[@id='154']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input")`? Is the element created dynamically? Have you tried waiting for it to become present or visible?

Comment: I checked that element using Firepath in Firefox browser and it is mentioned below " <div class="nx-field nx-layout-above nx-modified required" data-uid="152">
<input/>"

Comment: Let me know what syntax I have to use to code the above firepath element

Comment: I used the webdriver wait command also but it is not working. Please find the code below "    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='154']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='154']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("Rose");"

Comment: @VaidyanathAnantharaman This is incredibly bad way to use xpath. Provide the related `html` to help you out with the xpath

Comment: html Xpath for that field is : /html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input

Comment: <div class="nx-basicfieldeditor-section">
<div class="nx-basicfieldeditor-section-header"></div>
<div class="nx-basicfieldeditor-section-body">
<div class="nx-basicfieldeditor-item">
<div class="nx-basicfieldeditor-item-label nx-layout-above required">
<div class="nx-field nx-layout-above nx-modified required" data-uid="104">
<input>

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way `Xpath` should be used, please go through the following link: so that you could understand it in a better way.

**http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/choosing-effective-xpath/**

Also it is always good practice to share you HTML code so that ppl could identify the problem.

Meanwhile your element can be found using `CSSSelector` also try this--

```
driver.findelement(by.cssSelector("input[id='154']")).clear();
driver.findelement(by.cssSelector("input[id='154']")).sendKeys("Rose");
```

Please let me know if this works..!!

Comment: What is your mail id? As I cannot paste or attach the entire html code

Comment: I tried your syntax above but still it is not working

Comment: Mail sent to your gmail. Please check

Comment: Hi... I did not get any reply on the mail that I had sent 3 days back